# Using Azure TableStorage in C# .NET Core - Nuget Package WindowsAzure.Storage Alternative

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, azure-table-storage

I'm in the middle of writing a new app to store logs in Table Storage in Azure.

This is how my storage object looks:

```
public class ErrorLog : TableEntity
{
    public static ErrorLog Create(DateTime dateTime, int httpStatusCode, string message)
        => new ErrorLog
        {
            PartitionKey = GetPartitionKey(dateTime),
            RowKey = GetRowKey(dateTime),
            HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode,
            Message = message,
        };

    public int HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public static string GetPartitionKey(DateTime dateTime) 
        => dateTime.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH");

    public static string GetRowKey(DateTime dateTime)
        => dateTime.ToString("mm_ss");
}
```

However, I'm trying to find the new NuGet package to use instead of "WindowsAzure.Storage" (which has been deprecated), to no avail.

Comment: What's wrong with `WindowsAzure.Storage`?

Comment: The package has been deprecated.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table is a new package to work with Azure Tables.

Comment: You can find what you should use on [package nuget site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

Comment: @SergeyVishnevsky, your comment to use [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) is correct. Can you please post that as answer.

Comment: I guess you didn't bother to go to the [deprecated package's NuGet.org page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and read the text that explicitly states `For table support, see Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table`.

Comment: @IanKemp , would you mind addressing your comment with @ :).

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT It's aimed at the question asker - Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to @ them in comments :/

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to stop the meaningless discussion, OP please take a look at my answer and close the topic :)

Comment: @lukaszberwid , no problem. Wanted to avoid any confusion in our comments. `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` (old) looks similar to `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` (new) in name. Easy to miss the subtle difference. While both @Ian Kemp and you referred the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` (old) in your comment overriding `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` (new) in my comment, I thought of pointing that out. But now since you clearly mentioned in your answer, it is fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) has been deprecated. Package [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) is in maintenance mode and it will be deprecated soon. You should use [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) library can also be used to access Azure Storage Tables.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table is a new package to work with Azure Tables. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table